# \big delimiters not working with scrartcl?

Tags: fontsize, delimiters

I noticed that sometimes the `\big` delimiters stop working. One example is when `scrartcl` is the document class.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    (\frac{1}{2})
    \bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I obtain the following result (i.e., the `\bigl`/`\bigr` macros have no effect):

[image: big not working]

(The bigger delimiter macros such as `\Big` and `\bigg` seem to work though.)

Another example is when loading both `breqn` and `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    (\frac{1}{2})
    \bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug? What would be a possible workaround?

Comment: This is due to `scrartcl` using 11pt by default. Either load `\usepackage{exscale}` or, better `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: I don't think so. I just found another example: using the `article` document class, and loading both `mathtools` and `breqn` also disables `\big`. This is unrelated to `scrartcl` as I was suspecting. What do you think is the explanation?

Comment: I suspect that `breqn` is the culprit in the second example. If I remove the call, I get bigger parentheses. The two problems are unrelated.

Comment: Well, `breqn` does not cause the problem by itself, it's the combination with `mathtools`. Perhaps both problems are unrelated. But how to explain that `\big` is broken in both cases, and none of the other delimiter macros are? Could it be a name clash of some sort?

Comment: @egreg I apologize, I hadn't read your first comment completely... Could you explain more? The problem persists with `\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}`, but is indeed fixed upon loading `\usepackage{amsmath}`. I don't understand any of this... :-(

Comment: So, here is my solution so far: use `scrartcl` with `amsmath`, and disable either `mathtools` or `breqn`. I will disable `breqn` because I hardly ever use it. Feel free to add an answer that I can vote for! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `\big` is defined in the LaTeX kernel does not make it scale when the main font size is increased: here's the code from `fontmath.ltx`

```
524 \def\big#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to8.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
525 \def\Big#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to11.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
526 \def\bigg#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to14.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
527 \def\Bigg#1{{\hbox{$\left#1\vbox to17.5\p@{}\right.\n@space$}}}
```

Then `\bigl(` is just `\mathopen{\big{(}}`. You can see that the size of the delimiters does not depend from the main font size, but it's hardwired. Thus, when 11pt or 12pt size is used, `\big` ends up not being distinguishable from the normal size of the delimiter.

The `amsmath` package obviates to this by defining

```
552 \renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@\@ne}
553 \renewcommand{\Big}{\bBigg@{1.5}}
554 \renewcommand{\bigg}{\bBigg@\tw@}
555 \renewcommand{\Bigg}{\bBigg@{2.5}}
556 \def\bBigg@#1#2{%
557   {\@mathmeasure\z@{\nulldelimiterspace\z@}%
558      {\left#2\vcenter to#1\big@size{}\right.}%
559    \box\z@}}
560 \addto@hook\every@math@size{%
561   \global\big@size 1.2\ht\Mathstrutbox@
562   \global\advance\big@size 1.2\dp\Mathstrutbox@ }
563 \newdimen\big@size
```

and defining suitably `\Mathstrutbox@`. Essentially the same is done by the `exscale` package. Nothing is done to this by `mathtools`, so the relevant package is `amsmath`.

I believe there is a bug in the `breqn` package, because `\big@size` is not set to the same value as with `amsmath`: with this example input

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\makeatletter\showthe\big@size\makeatother
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I get

```
> 11.99995pt.
l.8 \makeatletter\showthe\big@size
                                  \makeatother
```

while uncommenting the call to `breqn` gives

```
> 7.20004pt.
l.8 \makeatletter\showthe\big@size
                                  \makeatother
```

and this difference explains why `\bigl(` is not larger than the simple `(`.